# Can you explain the behaviour of aggregations with inner join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of aggregations when the columns being aggregated are from tables in the join clauses.

So the scenarios I setup is this:
Imagine some struct with one to many properties

```
class X {
  String[] str;
  int ints[];
  float floats[];
}
```

This then gets represented by two tables

```
CREATE TABLE count_test.aggs (
    inst varchar(100) NULL,
    id varchar(100) NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE count_test.scalars (
    inst varchar(100) NULL,
    id varchar(100) NULL,
    str varchar(100) NULL,
    `int` INT NULL,
    `float` FLOAT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

I insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO aggs VALUES 
("inst1", "id1"),
("inst2", "id2"),
("inst3", "id3"),
("inst4", "id4"),
("inst5", "id5");

INSERT INTO scalars VALUES
('inst1', 'id1', 'str1', 1, 1.1),
('inst1', 'id1', 'str2', 2, 1.2),
('inst1', 'id1', 'str3', 3, 1.3),
('inst1', 'id1', 'str4', 4, 1.4),
('inst1', 'id1', 'str5', 5, 1.5),

('inst2', 'id2', NULL, 5, 2.1),
('inst2', 'id2', NULL, 6, 2.2),
('inst2', 'id2', NULL, 7, 2.3),
('inst2', 'id2', NULL, 7, 2.4),
('inst2', 'id2', 'str6', 8, 2.5),

('inst3', 'id3', NULL, 8, 3.1),
('inst3', 'id3', NULL, 9, 3.2),
('inst3', 'id3', NULL, 10, 3.3),
('inst3', 'id3', NULL, 11, 3.4),
('inst3', 'id3', 'str7', 12, 3.5),

('inst4', 'id4', 'str8', 13, 4.1),
('inst4', 'id4', 'str9', 14, 4.2),
('inst4', 'id4', 'str10', 15, 4.3),
('inst4', 'id4', NULL, 16, 4.4),
('inst4', 'id4', 'str7', 17, 4.5),

('inst4', 'id4', 'str8', 13, 4.1),
('inst4', 'id4', 'str9', 14, 4.2),
('inst4', 'id4', 'str10', 15, 4.3),
('inst4', 'id4', NULL, 16, 4.4),
('inst4', 'id4', 'str11', 17, 4.5),

('inst5', 'id5', 'str12', 18, 5.1),
('inst5', 'id5', 'str13', 19, 5.2),
('inst5', 'id5', 'str13', 20, 5.3),
('inst5', 'id5', 'str14', 21, 5.4),
('inst5', 'id5', 'str15', 22, 5.5);
```

And then the query I thought I'd write to find the `count`, `sum`, `avg` etc is

```
SELECT COUNT(s0.`str`) AS h1_c10,
 COUNT(s1.`str`) AS h1_c11,
 SUM(s2.`int`) AS h1_s10,
 SUM(s3.`float`) AS h1_s11,
 AVG(s4.`float`) AS h1_a10,
 MAX(s5.`float`) AS h1_m10,
 MIN(s6.`float`) AS h1_m11
FROM aggs h1
 INNER JOIN scalars s0 ON h1.inst = s0.inst AND h1.id = s0.id 
 INNER JOIN scalars s1 ON h1.inst = s1.inst AND h1.id = s1.id
 INNER JOIN scalars s2 ON h1.inst = s2.inst AND h1.id = s2.id
 INNER JOIN scalars s3 ON h1.inst = s3.inst AND h1.id = s3.id
 INNER JOIN scalars s4 ON h1.inst = s4.inst AND h1.id = s4.id
 INNER JOIN scalars s5 ON h1.inst = s5.inst AND h1.id = s5.id
 INNER JOIN scalars s6 ON h1.inst = s6.inst AND h1.id = s6.id
WHERE h1.inst = "inst1"
GROUP BY h1.inst, h1.id
```

The result in MariaDB is:
[image: Query result]

My instinct here is that the cartesian product of `h1 X s0 X s1...X s6` is being done but I don't have much more than that.
What I wanted, expected even, was 5 for the count since `h1.inst = 'inst1'` in the query.

Can someone help me understand why this is the result and how this should be written to `count`, `sum` only the rows from `scalars` where `inst = 'inst1'` or whatever the constraint is?

Comment: Not grouping on selected columns(the non aggregated)  could well give surprising results. If you want aggregation over the entire resultset then leave out the group by

Comment: hmmm, my GROUP BY is off. It's not obvious to me what GROUP BY could be used in this case to achieve the desired result though...`inst and id` where what I thought

Comment: Add sample data for aggs please. note aggs id is int and scalars is varchar - does it make sense to have these tested in the joins?

Comment: Added the sample data I have for aggs. The id in aggs is varchar, same as in scalars...or I'm misunderstanding what you're referring to.

Comment: @zcourts what is your expected output?

Comment: If there are not too many `FLOATs`, make them columns in the main table -- no `JOINs` needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with only 1 join:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.`str`) AS h1_c10,
       COUNT(s.`str`) AS h1_c11,
       SUM(s.`int`) AS h1_s10,
       SUM(s.`float`) AS h1_s11,
       AVG(s.`float`) AS h1_a10,
       MAX(s.`float`) AS h1_m10,
       MIN(s.`float`) AS h1_m11
FROM aggs a INNER JOIN scalars s 
ON a.inst = s.inst AND a.id = s.id 
WHERE a.inst = 'inst1'
GROUP BY a.inst, a.id
```

But actually, for this sample data, all you need is to aggregate in `scalars` only:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.`str`) AS h1_c10,
       COUNT(s.`str`) AS h1_c11,
       SUM(s.`int`) AS h1_s10,
       SUM(s.`float`) AS h1_s11,
       AVG(s.`float`) AS h1_a10,
       MAX(s.`float`) AS h1_m10,
       MIN(s.`float`) AS h1_m11
FROM scalars s 
WHERE s.inst = 'inst1'
GROUP BY s.inst, s.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b1f78150e2050a6e1a0d5bb53de5dbb2).
Results:

```
> h1_c10 | h1_c11 | h1_s10 | h1_s11 | h1_a10 | h1_m10 | h1_m11
> -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----:
>      5 |      5 |     15 |    6.5 |    1.3 |    1.5 |    1.1
```

Comment: By the time I saw your comment - you'd posted your answer. This is what I was expecting. I was over thinking this it seems. Thanks

Comment: I've been thinking this over and whilst your answer definitely addresses the example I gave, what if the join conditions were different. In my question, imagine each INNER JOIN s0, s1 had another field that was different so the resulting rows from Scalars was different for each of the JOINs I had. How would that be addressed. Would I simply have to write a query per unique JOIN criteria or can it be expressed in one SQL query?

Comment: The code depends on the requirement. Post a question with sample data and expected results for this case to clarify what you want.